# Запуск программы с параметром: точный путь неизвестен

Tags: windows, bat, командная-строка

На клиентских ПК установлено некоторое ПО "ПРОГРАММА", "ПРОГРАММА" может иметь разные версии, и, соответственно, установлено по разным путям. Есть файл, имеющий некое расширение ".XXX", это расширение ассоциировано с "ПРОГРАММА", т.е. при даблклике в проводнике Windows по этому файлу открывается "ПРОГРАММА" с содержимым файла. При вводе в командной строке пути к этому файлу также открывается "ПРОГРАММА". Здесь все нормально.

Теперь задача: нужно открыть определенный файл, имеющий расширение ".XXX" в "ПРОГРАММА", но с дополнительным параметром (он известен).

Как это сделать средствами командной строки?

Если это невозможно, могу написать приложение (C#), которое будет брать где-то в реестре путь к программе ассоциированной с расширением ".XXX" и запускать, но, при условии, что это не потребует каких-то привилегий.

ОС: Windows 7 SP1

---

Пример для воспроизведения проблемы:

Имеется установленный [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), он ассоциирован с текстовыми файлами с расширением ".TXT", также у него имеется параметр `-ro` для открытия файла в режиме только для чтения. Путь до самого приложения неизвестен.

Если я в командной строке ввожу

```
"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1.txt"
```

то файл открывается в нормальном режиме

Если ввожу:

```
"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" "C:\Users\User\Desktop\1.txt" -ro
```

то в режиме только для чтения.

Но путь "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" мне неизвестен, поэтому я открываю так:

```
"C:\Users\User\Desktop\1.txt"
```

файл открывается в обычном режиме

Если же ввожу:

```
"C:\Users\User\Desktop\1.txt" -ro
```

то файл все равно открывается в обычном режиме

Как мне открыть файл в режиме только для чтения, но при этом путь к исполняемому файлу неизвестен. Менять ассоциации файлов мне не подойдет.

Comment: Что вы пытались сделать для решения проблемы?

Comment: @sanmai, пробовал в командной строке запускать так: `"путь\к\файлу.XXX" /параметр` - "ПРОГРАММА" запускается с этим файлом, но без учета параметра

Comment: В вопрос добавьте, пожалуйста, что вы пробовали сделать. У других должна быть возможность повторить вашу проблему. Если проблему нельзя повторить, то это оффтопик.

Comment: @sanmai что именно вам не удается повторить?

Comment: @sanmai вариант задачи без сторонних программ: требуется запустить `notepad.exe file1.txt /foo`, но без использования переменных окружения %windir% и %path%

Comment: То есть нужно запустить программу где бы она не находилась? Грубо говоря, если есть программа, которая открывает файлы типа `.txt`, то нужно запустить её же с дополнительным ключом.

Comment: Дополнил ответ примером с Notepad++, который вы можете у себя воспроизвести, @sanmai

Comment: Найти программу, ассоциированную с каким-то типом, можно так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162331/finding-the-default-application-for-opening-a-particular-file-type-on-windows (полный ответ написать и проверить сейчас нет возможности)

Comment: @sanmai, в первую очередь интересуют решения без написания дополнительного лаунчера, т.к. это добавит хрупкости решению

Comment: [Посмотрите в ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162331/finding-the-default-application-for-opening-a-particular-file-type-on-windows) что я привёл - там готовый код для поиска программы с помощью `AssocQueryString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static string AssocQueryString(AssocStr association, string extension)
{
    const int S_OK = 0;
    const int S_FALSE = 1;

    uint length = 0;
    uint ret = AssocQueryString(AssocF.None, association, extension, null, null, ref length);
    if (ret != S_FALSE)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not determine associated string");
    }

    var sb = new StringBuilder((int)length); // (length-1) will probably work too as the marshaller adds null termination
    ret = AssocQueryString(AssocF.None, association, extension, null, sb, ref length);
    if (ret != S_OK)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not determine associated string"); 
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Вызывать с `AssocStr.ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE` и `".txt"`.

[Пример кода взят из другого ответа на английском.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162331/finding-the-default-application-for-opening-a-particular-file-type-on-windows)

Comment: Здесь более короткий способ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9540278/6766879 Если решение с командной строкой не будет найдено, то воспользуюсь им, спасибо за ссылки

Comment: Э... а куда вы дели импорт AssocQueryString через P/Invoke?

Comment: @PavelMayorov дополните ответ, что вам мешает

Answer (score 3):

В принципе установка ассоциации с типом файла позволяет выставить любой вызов который вам нужен. По умолчанию это выглядит как примерно как `prog.exe "%1"` где в `%1` идёт имя файла по которому кликнули. Можно это поменять с помощью `ftype` и `assoc`:

```
ftype MyProgramType=%ProgramFiles%\MyDir\MyProgram.exe "%1" /arg1 /arg2
assoc .xxx=MyProgramType
```

при даблклике или вызове из командной строки тогда помимо имени файла будут переданы `/arg1 /arg2`

Comment: Менять ассоциации я не хочу, на это есть причины: при даблклике должен остаться стандартный способ запуска + параметр мой может меняться, например `/foo 1`, `/foo 2`, `/foo bar` и т.д.

Comment: @Андрей можно добавить дополнительный способ запуска в контекстное меню, но я не помню как

Comment: @PavelMayorov, к сожалению, это тоже не подойдет, мне нужен именно запуск командой командной строки Windows

Comment: @Андрей тогда к сожалению ваше желание неосуществимо. Вызов программы по имени файла эквивалентен дабл-клику по этому файлу. Это передаёт единственный параметр в виде имени файла и вызывается ассоциированная команда. Всё остальное будет проигнорировано.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin, нет ли команды обратной `assoc`, чтобы по расширению получить путь?

Comment: Хм, нашел это: http://ab57.ru/cmdlist/assoc.html можно по идее написать `assoc .xxx`, но это почему-то не для всех расширений работает, в частности для моего, что печально

Comment: @Андрей, но ты же знаешь класс, который пишет программа? Вот, например, запрос для Visual Studio hpp независимо от версии: `ftype | find "VisualStudio" | find "hpp"` У меня выводится вот такое: `VisualStudio.hpp.14.0="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /dde`

Comment: @Qwertiy: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/721165/Запуск-программы-с-параметром-точный-путь-неизвестен/721172?noredirect=1#comment1091251_723296

Answer (score 0):

В качестве возможной идеи, можно добавить ваше приложение в [App Paths](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110725-00/?p=10073). При этом его можно будет запускать без полного пути и под альтернативным именем:

```
n -ro text.txt
```

Но если идти этим путём, можно и просто положить bat-файл с новым названием в доступном месте.

Comment: Путь заведомо неизвестен и на разных клиентских ПК может отличаться

Comment: Ну, решение как бы один раз на инсталляцию, так что если ставите программу вы сами, это можно сделать. Но если программа уже поставлена, тут всё хуже.

Answer (score 0):

Я когда-то решал задачу запуска Access-а, который мог быть установлен по разным путям. Брал путь установки из реестра.

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1 tokens=2,*" %%i in ('reg query 
"HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Office\11.0\Access\InstallRoot" /v "Path"') do set PathToAccess="%%j"
cd /d %PathToAccess%\
start msaccess.exe P:\Bank\CredStage\Orders_journal.mde /WRKGRP P:\Bank\CredStage\Security.mdw
```

Comment: Я попробовал уже несколько вариантов, но оказалось всё гораздо запутаннее - при клике по файлу запускается лаунчер, который уже запускает основное приложение, но если запускать этот лаунчер с дополнительным параметром - он его не передает основному приложению. Я сначала написал свой лаунчер, который искал информацию о приложении в реестре и запускал, но в итоге побоялся что это хрупкое решение и переложил ответственность на пользователя - теперь ему нужно указать путь к приложению вручную, он сохранится и будет использоваться.